# Why does this regex not work: '\([0-9a-zA-z]*\)';

Tags: regex

What I'd like to do remove the part of a string that is contained in brackets.

So for example be able to go from "Hello (World)" to "Hello".

I am using `var input2 = '\([0-9a-zA-z]*\)';` as my expression statement, and using regular expressions to match this pattern.

Can someone tell me what I'm going wrong?  I must be escaping the "(" and ")" incorrectly.

Comment: What language are we dealing with here?

Answer (score 4):

`A-z` should be `A-Z`.

If you want to be safe with those backslashes, escape the backslashes so you get `\\(` and `\\)` respectively, although I see nothing wrong with the backslashes.

Comment: Don;t think that [A-z] will stop it mathcing.  That matches A-Z [\]^_` and a-z

Comment: @justintime: I don't think he meant that as a solution.  But `[A-z]` is obviously a typo, and we would be remiss if we didn't point it out.

Answer (score 0):

Is this JavaScript?  If so, you either need to escape the backslashes like @BoltClock said, or use a regex literal:

```
var input2 = /\([0-9a-zA-Z]*\)/;
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why?  I can't correct my mistake if I don't know what it is. :D